# Why doesn't my Trane rooftop furnace ignite?

Tags: hvac

I’m having problems with my Trane model Yc0060C3H0AA rooftop unit. My inducer motor comes on, my igniter lights up and I can smell the gas valve opening up but my burners will not light.

Serial # g081422350

Comment: Welcome. Model number, please. What type of igniter is it?

Comment: Yc0060C3H0AA, Trane

Comment: Serial # g081422350

Answer (score 2):

**CHECK FOR GAS AND THAT IT IS GOING IN THE RIGHT PLACE**

I would check the gas pressure and the orifices or venturi. If a bug got in the orifice closest to the igniter gas will flow to the other burners but may not ignite. A bug in the venturi can disrupt the flow and cause a failure to ignite. Low inlet or outlet gas pressure could have the same effect.

**This is in respect to a barbeque but the premise is the same**
[image]www.barbequeworld.com

**This is where the orifices attach**
[image]www.repairclinic.com

**And this is what the burner should look like**[image]www.repairclinic.com

Comment: I have had tiny spiders plug the ports on outdoor equipment causing the gas to be blocked, cleaning them out has fixed the problem many times.+

Comment: The little buggers seem to love pilot tubes. I've cleaned dead spider husks and live one's numbering in the hundreds. HSI was probably developed because of spiders.

Comment: Now would a crack heat exchanger cause this problem?

Comment: I'd say if it were a crack causing it, it would have to be a massive crack. Plus the blower usually activates about a minute after the call for heat. The gas valve usually opens after about 30 seconds after the call.